# problem in Labels with asterisk!

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following ASP.NET markup:

```
<td align="right" valign="top" style="width: 130px">
    Answer: <asp:Label 
                 ID="lblanswer" 
                 runat="server" 
                 CssClass="errorMessage" 
                 ForeColor="Red"
                 Text="*">
            </asp:Label>
</td>
```

I want it to say "Answer:*" with only the asterisk in red.

How to do that if I want Answer to be inside the `<asp:label/>`.

Comment: Wish I could vote to reopen, since it appears to be a real question now...

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
TextBox textBox1 = new TextBox();
textBox1.PasswordChar = '*';
```